# js count 15 min interval (double)

Tags: javascript, time, intervals, min, hour

In JS i've a var {double} hour, where i want to know how many 15 minutes are in there.

```
// Example
var hour = 2.30
// Example calculation
// 1 hour = 60*60 = 3600
// 2 hour = 60*120 = 7200
// 15 min = 60 * 15 = 900
// 30 min = 60 * 30 = 1800
// count 15min within hour
var result = 7200 + 1800 = 9000 / 900 = 10
```

I can count the hours like this

```
var hour = 2.30
var tmp_hour = parseInt((hour.toString().split('.')[0]) * 60 * 60);
// tmp_hour = 7200
```

But i can't find a way to calculate the fractioanal part to minutes, see code

```
// this only working with::
// hour = 2.15, 2.45

// hour 2.15 => result => 900 (correct)
// hour 2.45 => result => 2700 (correct)
// hour 2.30 => result => 180 (not correct)
var tmp_min  = parseInt(hour.toString().split('.')[1] / 15 * 900);
```

Does someone nows a better way for calculating this.

And i've another question whats could be offtopic.

I have a table with a couple of cells. When i click on a cell its get divided into four pieces (time interval, where every piece stands for 15 min).

```
// example
<table>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
         <div class="divider">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This is working fine, but i want to calculate the width for every label (4 pieces).

For instance if the clicked cell has a width of 17 px.
I want to following width

```
// span 1: 4px    
// span 2: 5px    
// span 3: 4px    
// span 4: 4px 
// total: 17px
```

I've tried several calculation with mod and dividing but could not get the disired result.

Comment: So, `2.30` is supposed to be 2 hours and 30 minutes? That seems like a bad way to encode it. I'd suggest using "normal" fractions, e.g., `2.5 -> 2 and a half hours`, which means that your calculation is `hour * 60` to get the minutes and you can work from there. Either that or just use two variables.

Comment: I've tried it: 2.5 * 60 * 60 = 9000 / 900 = 10 and works :) But is looks weird that 2.30 hours is noted as 2.50 or am i wrong.

Comment: 2.5 -> two and a half. In terms of hours, half an hour is 30 minutes, of course but that's because of the transition to decimal.

Comment: Oke, thx. Do you maybe have a solution for my other problem @vlaz